# Tag synonym request: Hotmail -> Outlook

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Similar to SkyDrive/OneDrive - since Hotmail has been deprecated in favour of Outlook.com, there's no need for a separate [hotmail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotmail) tag, it should be a synonym for [outlook](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook).

(Technically the tag should be called "Outlook.com", but since no other meaning of Outlook applies to Windows Phone, I think just "Outlook" is fine.)

Comment: I'm a user (maybe I should cal myself a reseller) of Office 365. I ask my clients to login using outlook.com/theirdomain.com. So, it's a little bit confusing. Maybe disable [tag:outlook] and suggest to the user to use [tag:outlook.com], [tag:exchange-online] and [tag:outlook-desktop] (or whatever)?

Comment: Also, I don't know if Microsoft refer to the built-in email app in Windows Phone as Outlook. Do you?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder How is reselling Office 365 relevant to Windows Phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, I have nothing against it.

Comment: Done. I merged them too.

Comment: Just need to be careful that people aren't referring to the desktop software at the time, but that's what the tag wiki is to explain :)